# Using the TFS REST API to get all work items in an iteration

Tags: rest, tfs

I am attempting to get some information about all User Stories in the current sprint.  I can get the path to the current sprint easily, and given a list of the IDs for the work items I can get what I need from them, but I am unsure of how to get those IDs from just the iteration path.

I have seen an example of this using C# and queries, but I am using javascript and the REST API, and I would prefer not to user queries if possible.

Comment: There isn't any way to get this data directly without queries. What concern do you have with queries? If you don't use it, you may need to get all the work items first and then check their iteration path which is more complex and slow than use queries.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to achieve this is using [queries](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/using-queries) which designed to help you find work items that you want to review, triage, update, or list in a report.

The Work Item Query Language is also supported with REST API. There is a Parameter [System.IterationPath] which meets your requirement.

More detail info please refer:

> **Programmatically query for work items**
>
> • REST APIs: [Work item queries and query folders](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/api/wit/queries) and [Work item
>   query language](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql)

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I would prefer not to use queries.  Can this be done without them?

Comment: @Mystagogue  just like Eddie mentioned. Using other ways to achieve the requirement is much more complex than queries. Since you are using REST API. Strongly recommend you to use queries.

Answer (score 0):

The only generic solution I could find was to get all work items ids by iterating all pages from [Read Reporting Revisions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/Reporting%20Work%20Item%20Revisions/Read%20Reporting%20Revisions%20Get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=vsts-rest-5.0)

Then get bulks of work items from [List Work Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

Unfortunately TFS/AzureDevops do not offer a shorter path without using queries.