# Is the TFS REST API that compilcated when using it with stored queries?

Tags: c#, rest, tfs

It is mentioned here: [Using the TFS REST API to get all work items in an iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247599/using-the-tfs-rest-api-to-get-all-work-items-in-an-iteration)
and I am already working with the VS docs at https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/queries#get-a-query-or-folder

We try to generate a change log text file based on a stored query on the TFS server. Prior to the REST API we were using the VS 2012/2013 TFS library but are now shifting to REST.

Now by reading the docs I see that when querying work items I should do this for max 200 work items (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql#get-work-items)

If I understand the documentation correctly, then I need 6 http queries for a stored query that returns 607 work items.

1. Get Stored Query by name -> 
   `http://server/Project/_apis/wit/queries/Shared%20Queries/Change%20Log?api-version=1.0&$expand=all`, which returns the WIQL url for the query
2. Query WIQL -> returning 607 ids
3. Create a work item query for the first 200 work items
4. for the next 200
5. for the next 200
6. for the next 7

Then assemble those work items and format them according to the *display columns* configuration which is provided by query no. 1.

By testing the 200 work item limit I found out that the on premise installation actually allow more work items. Currently the max amount of work items is defined by the GET request length of 2096 (tested on TFS 2017).

Is this the confirmed approach on how to execute stored queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is the right approach.

Simple C# code to send REST API:

```
String MyURI = "[REST API URL]";
            WebRequest WReq = WebRequest.Create(MyURI);
            WReq.Credentials =
                new NetworkCredential("[user name]", "[password]", "[domain]");

            WebResponse response = WReq.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Display the content.
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
```

On the other hand, you can [run the query with WIQL string](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql).

Regarding to get WIQL string of stored query, you can use TFS .net client API.

```
NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("[user name]", "[password]", "[domain]");
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("[collection URL"), cred);
            tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
            WorkItemStore wis = tpc.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore)) as WorkItemStore;
 QueryHierarchy queryRoot = wis.Projects["[team project]"].QueryHierarchy;
            QueryFolder queryFolder = queryRoot["Shared Queries"] as QueryFolder;
            QueryDefinition qd = queryFolder["PBIS"] as QueryDefinition;
            string tt = qd.QueryText;
```

Regarding call query REST API with [Extended Client package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/), you can refer to this simple code:

```
var u = new Uri("[collection url]");
VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential("v-stache", "Hua543@Hua543", "fareast")));
            var connection = new VssConnection(u, c);
            var workitemClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
 var result = workitemClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models.Wiql() { Query = "select[System.Id] from WorkItems where [System.TeamProject] = 'ScrumStarain2' and [System.WorkItemType] = 'Product Backlog Item' and [System.State] <> ''" }, "ScrumStarain2").Result;
```

Comment: We were using the TFS .net client API but it seems that it is no longer available in 2015. Our CI with 2015 only builds the code but ends up with missing satellite assemblies.

Comment: @Samuel the TFS client API still work for 2015, you can open the new thread for your issues.

Comment: @samuel, the 2015 Client API is available on Nuget as the "Team Foundation Server Extended API"... Just add it to your project.

Comment: Good grief, how did I missed that TFS Api is still maintained. Thanks for pointing it out starain-MSFT and @MrHinsh