# How to page results from TFS WorkItemTrackingHttpClient QueryByWiqlAsync

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm using WorkItemTrackingHttpClient.QueryByWiqlAsync to retrieve the results of a query. It returns the top 200 records by default. It has a top param which you can use to specify a value less then 200.

However, the result of my query is greater than 200 records. Does anyone know how to execute a query using the TFS client with proper paging .i.e. page and page size? For example, return page 10 where the page count is say 50.

I've looked around but can't see how to do this using the client which is surprising as the capability seems so fundamental.

I'm using the Nuget Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client 16.153.0. I'm also connecting to TFS 2017 onprem.

Comment: would you please share us the latest information in your side? Could you get helpful suggestions from Andy's answer?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, we can only return a list of work items which limits to Maximum 200 by calling the API. It's by design, see [Work Items - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) for details.

However we can use WIQL Queries to retrieve data from Azure DevOps. It is very flexible and it could be used in any situation. See [WIQL queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/wiql-syntax?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts) and [Azure DevOps Rest API for WIQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

To get all the work items, we can try following steps:

1. Execute a stored query using the work item query API to retrieve a
   list of work item IDs
2. **Split the list of work item IDs into groups of 200**, which is the
   maximum batch size that the work items API supports
3. Call the work items API for each list of 200 work item IDs to get
   the work item details.

You can reference [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163545/is-the-tfs-rest-api-that-compilcated-when-using-it-with-stored-queries) for details.

Besides, below code for your reference, it's working for me:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace QueryWorkitems0619
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://tfs2017:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection");

            //string PAT = "xxxx";
            string project = "SCRUM-TFVC";

            //VssBasicCredential credentials = new VssBasicCredential(user, PAT);

            VssCredentials credentials = new VssClientCredentials();
            credentials.Storage = new VssClientCredentialStorage();

        //create a wiql object and build our query
        Wiql wiql = new Wiql()
        {
            Query = "Select * " +
                    "From WorkItems " +
                    "Where [Work Item Type] = 'Product Backlog Item' " +
                    "And [System.TeamProject] = '" + project + "' " +
                    "And [System.State] <> 'Closed' " +
                    "Order By [State] Asc, [Changed Date] Desc"
        };

        //create instance of work item tracking http client
        using (WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingHttpClient = new WorkItemTrackingHttpClient(uri, credentials))
        {
            //execute the query to get the list of work items in the results
            WorkItemQueryResult workItemQueryResult = workItemTrackingHttpClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(wiql).Result;

            //Splict the query result (the list of work item IDs) into groups of 200.
            var QueryGroups = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, workItemQueryResult.WorkItems.Count())
                            group workItemQueryResult.WorkItems.ToList()[i] by i / 200;

            foreach (var QueryGroup in QueryGroups)
            {
                //some error handling                
                if (QueryGroup.Count() != 0)
                {
                    //need to get the list of our work item ids and put them into an array
                    List<int> list = new List<int>();
                    foreach (var item in QueryGroup.ToList())
                    {
                        list.Add(item.Id);
                    }
                    int[] arr = list.ToArray();

                    //build a list of the fields we want to see
                    string[] fields = new string[3];
                    fields[0] = "System.Id";
                    fields[1] = "System.Title";
                    fields[2] = "System.State";

                    //get work items for the ids found in query
                    var workItems = workItemTrackingHttpClient.GetWorkItemsAsync(arr, fields, workItemQueryResult.AsOf).Result;

                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n----------------------------------------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("\nQuery Results: {0} items found for Group {1}", workItems.Count, QueryGroup.Key);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n----------------------------------------------------------------");

                    //loop though work items and write to console
                    foreach (var workItem in workItems)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ID:{0} Title:{1}  State:{2}", workItem.Id, workItem.Fields["System.Title"], workItem.Fields["System.State"]);
                    }         
                }                 
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: @PatrickNolan I have updated the code which can split the query result into groups, it works for me, it can show all the work items. In my example, the query result is split into 6 groups. Just have a try for that.

Answer (score 0):

[Andy's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59821220/1728856) was too slow for queries returning around 300k records. Here is a slightly modified version of his code which performs much better on my side:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace QueryWorkitems0619
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://tfs2017:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection");

            //string PAT = "xxxx";
            string project = "SCRUM-TFVC";

            //VssBasicCredential credentials = new VssBasicCredential(user, PAT);

            VssCredentials credentials = new VssClientCredentials();
            credentials.Storage = new VssClientCredentialStorage();

        //create a wiql object and build our query
        Wiql wiql = new Wiql()
        {
            Query = "Select * " +
                    "From WorkItems " +
                    "Where [Work Item Type] = 'Product Backlog Item' " +
                    "And [System.TeamProject] = '" + project + "' " +
                    "And [System.State] <> 'Closed' " +
                    "Order By [State] Asc, [Changed Date] Desc"
        };

        //create instance of work item tracking http client
        using (WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingHttpClient = new WorkItemTrackingHttpClient(uri, credentials))
        {
            //execute the query to get the list of work items in the results
            WorkItemQueryResult workItemQueryResult = workItemTrackingHttpClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(wiql).Result;

            //Cagin's modification starts here:
            List<WorkItemReference> workItems = workItemQueryResult.WorkItems.ToList();
            int count = workItems.Count;

            // Split the query result (the list of work item IDs) into groups of 200.
            var QueryGroups =
                from i in Enumerable.Range(0, count)
                group workItems[i] by i / 200;
            //Cagin's modification ends here.

            foreach (var QueryGroup in QueryGroups)
            {
                //some error handling                
                if (QueryGroup.Count() != 0)
                {
                    //need to get the list of our work item ids and put them into an array
                    List<int> list = new List<int>();
                    foreach (var item in QueryGroup.ToList())
                    {
                        list.Add(item.Id);
                    }
                    int[] arr = list.ToArray();

                    //build a list of the fields we want to see
                    string[] fields = new string[3];
                    fields[0] = "System.Id";
                    fields[1] = "System.Title";
                    fields[2] = "System.State";

                    //get work items for the ids found in query
                    var workItems = workItemTrackingHttpClient.GetWorkItemsAsync(arr, fields, workItemQueryResult.AsOf).Result;

                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n----------------------------------------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("\nQuery Results: {0} items found for Group {1}", workItems.Count, QueryGroup.Key);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n----------------------------------------------------------------");

                    //loop though work items and write to console
                    foreach (var workItem in workItems)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ID:{0} Title:{1}  State:{2}", workItem.Id, workItem.Fields["System.Title"], workItem.Fields["System.State"]);
                    }         
                }                 
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```